# Is "like when" grammatical in the following?

Tags: grammaticality

> She was furious at him, *like when* he broke her vase.

Is *like when* grammatical? Why?

I thought of using *as when* but it sounds a little off to me for some reason.

Comment: I find it very informal; it should  correctly be "like/as she had been when..."

Comment: What does 'broke her base' mean?

Comment: It's fine, though informal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *She was furious at him, like when he broke her vase.*

Leaving aside its verbal use, "like" belongs to both adjective and preposition categories.

When it occurs in a comparative construction, as in your example, it's a preposition with a preposition phrase in a 'fused' relative construction as complement.

We can paraphrase it as

*She was furious at him, like on the occasion when he broke her vase.*

Comment: So it's grammatical? It's a short form of: "She was furious at him, like (on the occasion) when he broke her vase."?

Comment: @alexchenco Yes, it's grammatical, though informal. "Like when he broke the vase" is much more natural than "on the occasion when he broke the vase", though it means the same.

Comment: Thanks, one last question: what about "as when"?

Comment: @alexchenco Yes, it's OK, as in "She was furious at him, **as when** he broke her vase".

Answer (score 2):

In American English for the last 30 years, there has been a proliferation of “like” as a generic conjunction, particularly in the speech of people born after 1970. Unfortunately, because it is generic, its meaning is often vaporous.

If we view grammar purely descriptively, then we have to say that your sentence is grammatical in current American speech although meaningless.

If, however, we view grammar more prescriptively, then the sentence is not only meaningless but also ungrammatical.

In short, the sentence is fashionably inarticulate. The most likely meaning is

> She was just as furious at him as when he broke her vase.

Comment: Its use as a conjunction in American usage was common much earlier than you suggest. Wikipedia documents the notorious advertising slogan [Winston tastes good like a cigarette should](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winston_tastes_good_like_a_cigarette_should), which was created in 1954. The usage was considered inappropriate then, but the slogan would not have been created if it were not common.

Comment: @JeffreyCarney Oh I am well aware of the usage of “like” as a substitute for “as” well before the 1980’s. My point is rather the wholesale use of “like” as a general purpose word to be inserted *ad libitum* in speech. That was not common in the 50’s and 60’s.